# How can I add one disk to an existing raidz zpool?

Tags: solaris, zfs, raidz

I have an OpenSolaris server with a zpool `backupz` comprised of four SCSI drives:

```
-bash-3.2# zpool status backupz
  pool: backupz
 state: ONLINE
 scrub: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        backupz     ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c7t0d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c7t1d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c7t2d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c7t3d0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I want to add a fifth drive... but `zpool add backupz raidz c7t4d0` isn't working...

```
-bash-3.2# zpool add backupz raidz c7t4d0
invalid vdev specification: raidz requires at least 2 devices
```

Can I not have a raidz config with 5 devices? Do I have to add two devices at once? or am I doing something incorrect altogether here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't expand an existing raidz vdev, you have to blow it away and create it again with the new drive(s). See the other answer for better details.

Side note: Someone actually worked out that it's technically possibly to add drives to a raidz, but the functionality hasn't been implemented. The same is true of removing a disk.

Comment: Uh oh. If that's the case I've made a terrible decision somewhere! =o

Comment: -1 Of course a zpool can be expanded. What do you think the `zpool add` command does? The limitation which Josh is running into, is that you can't change the composition of a raidz vdev ("raidz1" in his example). You can add new devices to the pool itself just fine. This is one of the reason why mirror vdevs are preferred: http://serverfault.com/questions/63809/zfs-mirror-vs-raid-z

Comment: @Wim, I'm well aware that you can add additional vdevs to a pool. It was a minor typo, and there's no reason to jump all over me like that.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know someone found a way to work around the architecture to allow adding drives! Do you have a link where I can read more on it?

Answer (score 33):

See this thread from one of the FreeBSD lists: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-fs/2009-June/006327.html

To quote Dan Naumov,

> To reiterate, you cant just add a single disk drive to a raidz1 or
>   raidz2 pool. This is a known limitation (you can check with SUN ZFS
>   docs). If you have an existing raidz and you MUST increase that
>   particular pool's storage capabilities, you have 3 options:
>
> 1) Add a raidz of the same configuration to the pool (think 3 disk
>   raidz + 3 disk raidz or 5 + 5, for example)
>
> 2) Replace each (and every) disk in your raidz pool one by one,
>   letting it resilver after inserting each upgraded disk
>
> 3) Backup your data, destroy your pool and create a new raidz pool
>   with a bigger amount of disks.

Comment: +1: Thanks @brent! Your answer was more detailed than Chris' however he was providing me with detailed info in chat, so I accepted his answer. I appreciate the information!

Comment: Why must one add a RAIDZ of the same configuration and can't e.g. add a RAIDZ with 8 disks to one with 3? Isn't data striped across all VDEVs aka RAIDZs?

Comment: @Thorsten Schöning The answer is performance, ZFS performs best with VDEVs of the same size: https://serverfault.com/a/564436/333397